# Is there difference between "fake German accent" and "German fake accent"

Tags: meaning

Is there difference between "fake German accent" and "German fake accent"

I think "fake German accent" and "German fake accent" are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"fake German accent" is a person pretending to have a German accent (but not doing it well) The Nazis in the war films were played by Americans with fake German accents.

"German fake accent" is not used, and so doesn't have an idiomatic meaning.  I'd assume it was just an error or variation on "fake German accent" and not try to analyse it any further.

As a learner, only use the order "fake German accent" in your writing.

Comment: Would this famous utterance be a 'German fake accent'? _eating lots of chips and fish and hole in the toads, and Dundee cakes on Piccadilly line. Don't you know old chap I was head of Gestapo for ten years. Five years! No, no, nein, I was not head of Gestapo at all...I make joke._

Comment: perhaps, but I did a search for "German fake accent" and every instance of it was just the same meaning as "fake german accent" but either in very casual context of by a non-native English speaker.  EG "and he had this totally cringe german fake accent" (on X by some woman talking about her date)

Comment: James K, I make joke!